# StackExchange box is transparent and too big

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Clicking on the StackExchange box in the top-left opens a transparent (no background?) box that covers most of the page in overlapping text. Opening this box on other sites (like Stack Overflow) opens a solid box, about 300 pixels on a side.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed.

Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: While this has been fixed the count of how many things are in my inbox is showing up either below the stack exchange drop down or off to the left of it. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @yossarian - subtle, and also fixed now.